# Grails URL Api Mapping is calling wrong controller

Tags: grails, urlmappings.groovy

I've got two controllers.
PollController and api.PollApiController.

My PollController is just a normal controller.
The API-Controller inherits the RestfulController:

```
class PollApiController extends RestfulController {

    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    PollApiController() {
        super(Poll)
    }
}
```

These are my URL-Mappings:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/api/poll"(resources:'poll', controller:'pollApiController')
    }
}
```

My problem is that every time I do a /api-Call grails runs the PollController instead of PollApiController. I can check it if I alter the PollController. 
It's the first time I work with the RestfulController, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you map to a `RestfulController`, you don't need the `controller` parameter. Instead, `resources` should be set to the base name of your (Restful) Controller.

```
"/api/poll"(resources: 'pollApi')
```

For more detail, see: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#restfulMappings